# How to use variables in DOM CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I want to make my webpage responsive using javascript. Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work and how should i do this?

```
document.getElementById("id1").style.left = variable;
```

Comment: Can you create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question to include it? That line right there should work, assuming everything is setup correctly.

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? What's your "id1" and variable?

Comment: my id is "price_list" and variable is valid number

Comment: The `left` style requires units I believe. Try `...left = variable + 'px'`

Comment: @Dylan pixel is the default unit. I think it can be omitted.

Comment: @MartinBrláž You said your id is `price_list` then why are you using `id1`?

Comment: Please use your real code, and some of the code it works with for context .

Answer (score 1):

Very hard to understand what it is you are asking for however I created a fiddle that is passing a variable to show you the syntax. https://jsfiddle.net/b6cLt0td/1/

```
<div id="id1">

</div>
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="someFunc()"/>
<input type="button" value="move me" onclick="moveFunc()"/>
<script>
function someFunc(){
var red ="red";

document.getElementById("id1").style.backgroundColor = red;
}
function moveFunc(){
var dist = 100;

document.getElementById("id1").style.left = dist +"px";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variable needs to be a string ending with `px`, e.g., `variable = "100px";`

For more detail on the `left` property:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_left.asp

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using jQuery:

```
$('#id1').css({
    left: variable
});
```

Also, just a suggestion, but in case you have not, you might want to consider making your page responsive by using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) instead of by using javascript.

[More on responsive design](https://responsivedesign.is/)